# Using RRAS results in bluescreens with 1E and 3C errors on things like Ping

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, rras, bsod

My whole class has a major problem with RRAS.

Let me first explain the situation.

For our project, we have to virtualize two servers (North and South)
each represents a location of the company, and they are connected via "WAN". (Which is, when virtualized, a virtual network.)

They both also have a adapter connected to their "LAN's". (LAN NORTH and LAN SOUTH)

we installed Windows Server 2008R2 Standard on both machines, installed ADDS, and put them in a domain together (ZH.NL)

So far so good. all of that works. we now have 2 servers, with a LAN side for the clients and a "WAN" side, the wan sides being connected with each other.

now the problem starts.

We install RRAS, we set it up to use the WAN adapter, and it installs correctly.

the problem is that as long as RRAS is activated, blue screens can happen on certain actions. (But not all of them happen every time!)
These actions include:

Pinging with north to the wan side of south (1E and 3C) (90% chance of BSOD)

While shutting down the server (1E) (20% chance of BSOD)

Creating a new user in active directory (Don't know which error code, sorry, server has been removed since) (about 10% chance of BSOD)

Logging on to the domain from a windows 7 client connected to one of the servers. (1E and 3C) (about 10% chance of BSOD)

Tested host operating systems include Windows 7, Windows 8, and OSX 10.8.4
Tested with VirtualBox and VMWare.

none of these factors seem to have any effect on the occurrence, and we're quite lost on where to look further.

I hope that someone can help.

Excuse me if I missed some information, I'd be happy to give further details if they might be of interest, and my apologies for any language mishaps. I'm not a native English speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know something you missed.
When you login on a client connected to one of the servers with the profilepath located on the server.
Results in bluescreen.
And you forgot to mention that the clients located in north need to be able to connect to the south server and clients in south to the server in north This is to let the employees work on both locations And that the hardware is not the issue.
Tested on both Intel and amd and on my home computer which has good pc specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late, but better than never.

Turned out that Windows Server 2008R2 is to blame for this. the same setup with Windows Server 2008 works perfectly fine.

That being said, RRAS is still a problematic thing in my experience, and I would advise people to look for different solutions.

Comment: A little late, but: done.